# eXist-db more secure alternative to system:as-user() to access account metadata

Tags: xquery, exist-db

In eXist 4.7 I have a web pages which can be visited by all visitors from `guest` to authenticated users. These pages result from XML documents which have editor user ID(s). In publishing these IDs, I want to convert them to the full name as found in `security manager account metadata`.

I have a function in module `user.xql` called `user:user-info($userid as xs:string)` which retrieves the needed data.

In my module `collection.xql` the function `collection:content` outputs the HTML for the page. Currently I use `system:as-user()` to obtain the info. In simplified fashion, it looks like this (where `$globalvar:ADMIN_PW_KEY` is the admin password variable):

```
module namespace collections="/db/apps/foo/modules/collections";

declare namespace tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0";

import module namespace user="/db/apps/foo/modules/user" at 
                               "/db/apps/foo/modules/user.xql";


declare function collections:content($node as node(), $model as map(*), 
                                       $ref as xs:string?)
{  
  let $doc := doc(concat("$mycollection",$ref )
  for each $editor in $doc//tei/editor/data(@nymRef)
  let $ed := system:as-user("admin",$globalvar:ADMIN_PW_KEY,user:user-info($editor))
  return concat($ed//firstname/(text(), " ", $ed//lastname/(text())
};
```

This works fine, except I'm not comfortable with having to store the admin password in a file.

I attempted to set the setuid/setgid permissions on the `user.xql`module  per the [documentation](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/security#permissions), up to and including all read/write/execute permissions, and adding all groups to the ACL with full permissions.

[image: permissions]

but eXist reported

```
  You must be a DBA to retrieve metadata about other users, 
  otherwise you may only retrieve metadata about yourself.
```

Are there any other secure solutions to accessing `account metadata`?

Many thanks.

Comment: How were you invoking the `user.xql`? If you are using it as a library module then set-uid/set-gid is ignored. set-uid and set-gid is only used when invoking a main module.

Comment: Invoked as `import module namespace user="/db/apps/foo/modules/user" at 
                               "/db/apps/foo/modules/user.xql";` i.e. as library module

Comment: Okay then setuid/setgid won't apply. Can you break it up into a sequence of main modules linked by http calls?

Comment: Yes, I have to rethink the strategy on this one. Obviously it could be done!